# iPhone SDK Modify WiFi Settings

Tags: iphone

I need to be able to modify the WiFi settings on a iOS device (iPhone and iPad), most of the libraries are found so far via google search are private libs... Apple don't like this, does the SDK allow this in another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without jail breaking the device, you cannot modify the Wi-Fi settings. This is because all iOS applications are sandboxed, meaning they only have access to the data Apple allow deems necessary to the functioning of the app. For iOS apps, the documents directory constitutes the application's sandbox and the application cannot create or modify files or directories outside of these directories.  So even if you found a way to modify Wi-Fi settings, your app would be rejected by Apple. Hope this helps!

Comment: Did they change their policy? :
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/qr-wifi/id462560581?mt=8

Comment: Nevermind. That app creates QR codes for your friends with android devices.. haha

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not expose any public APIs that allow you to do this.